# Which thread do animations run on?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-animation

The question may be somewhat vague. But suppose I have an ObjectAnimator and I run a long and slow translate animation, can I still interact with the UI while the animation is running? Eg. can I click on a button?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [are android animations always within the UI Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963715/are-android-animations-always-within-the-ui-thread)

Answer (score 1):

The animation started by calling `start()` method will be run on the thread that called this method. This thread should have a `Looper` on it (a runtime exception will be thrown if this is not the case). Also, if the animation will animate the properties of objects in the view hierarchy, then the calling thread should be the `UI thread` for that view hierarchy.